# Backup the data to cloud Periodically in iOS where the user selects the time at which the Backup should happen everyday

Tags: ios, swift

In my app , i need to take the data backup automatically every day at a specified time. This Should work even if the app is terminated.

So how to invoke or notify my app at the Set time to execute a block of code (even when app is terminated) which  will backup data to iCloud  but i dont want my app to open in foreground. This should happen in background.

Here i can set the timer and execute the stuff in background but how to notify app when it is terminated. Is this Possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use "Silent push notification" for the same, because you will loose your access after termination of the app.

Comment: Thanks for Reply . But for Silent push notification whether  i need a help of any server ? or how i trigger this for my delegate to be Called.